# RGB color space not permitted on grayscale

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I tried to convert PDF to PNGs

```
$ convert linkedList.pdf -quality 300 output.png
convert: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG `output.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1744.
```

Should I ignore the prompts?

I want best most quality PNGs.

Comment: Which is your version of ImageMagick? (`convert -version`)

Comment: I have the same issue, but it works correctly

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution to get rid of the warning: [Error in converting a PDF to a PNG in ImageMagick](https://superuser.com/a/1481216/221852)

```
convert linkedList.pdf -quality 300 -colorspace RGB output.png
```

With the PDF I used the resulting images look the same, whether I use the `colorspace` option or not. The result image with the `colorspace` option has a slightly larger file size, 16 Bytes in my case.